# show matrix like data in listview

Tags: asp.net, listview

i'm working on a advertising web site that shows its goods on one of pages.
i want to show that goods in a listview but i want to my list view shows its goods in matrix like view.
for example my listview reads data like name,description and image of goods and shows first four of those in first row  and next four in second row and so on.
could you please help me how do i do this? i want to use div ins Listview's Itemtemplate
is this  proper code for my reson?

```
<asp:DataList ID="datalist_Data" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <table>
        <tr style="background-color: #6699FF; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: large;">
            <td width="150">Column 1</td>
            <td width="150">Column 2</td>
            <td width="150">Column 3</td>
            <td width="150">Column 4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="150"><%# Eval("c1") %></td>
            <td width="150"><%# Eval("c2") %></td>
            <td width="150"><%# Eval("c3") %></td>
            <td width="150"><%# Eval("c4") %></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: So what you want is that in every cell, you display all product informations, and display 4 products in each row ?

Comment: i want something like what you see in amazon website 'http://www.amazon.com ' i want to show my products like that

Comment: or like this web site 'http://www.amazon.com/Pens-Refills-Writing-Correction-Supplies/b/ref=amb_link_378908382_5?ie=UTF8&node=1069820&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=center-8&pf_rd_r=0C37SGHH4HMNVSBTC2NE&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1576904702&pf_rd_i=507846'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataList has a set of property to deal with your problem : `RepeatColumns`, `RepeatDirection` and `RepeatLayout`

Read more about DataList control on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList.aspx)

Here's the code for your need (where `Foo`is the type of your good) :

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="datalist" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr style="background-color: #6699FF; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: large;">
                <td width="150">Column 1</td>
                <td width="150">Column 2</td>
                <td width="150">Column 3</td>
                <td width="150">Column 4</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemStyle Width="150" Wrap="true" />
    <ItemTemplate>

        <%# (Container.DataItem as Foo).Name %><br />
        <%# (Container.DataItem as Foo).Description %><br />
        <%# (Container.DataItem as Foo).ImageUrl %>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Note that this writing avoid the Eval, which is poorly effective since it requires reflection.

**EDIT :** Here's the C# code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Foo> list = GetGoods();

    datalist.DataSource = list;
    datalist.DataBind();
}
```